# Tasks and WaitAll\WhenAll

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

Could you help me to speed up/optimize this code:

```
// Get API Keys
var keys = xRoot.Elements("key").Select(key => new { ID = int.Parse(key.Attribute("id").Value), VerificationCode = key.Attribute("verificationCode").Value });

// Get status of account using API Key
var tasks = keys.Select(key => EveOnlineClient.GetAccountStatusAsync(key.ID, key.VerificationCode));

// Get info about API Key
// Each API key may contain one or more game characters
var tasks2 = keys.Select(key => EveOnlineClient.GetAPIKeyInfoAsync(key.ID, key.VerificationCode).ContinueWith(x =>
    {
        var characters = x.Result.Characters;

        // Get the sheet for each character in each API key
        var tasks3 = characters.Select(character => EveOnlineClient.GetCharacterSheetAsync(key.ID, key.VerificationCode, character.ID));

        // Get skill in training for each character in each API key
        var tasks4 = characters.Select(character => EveOnlineClient.GetSkillInTrainingAsync(key.ID, key.VerificationCode, character.ID));

        Task.WaitAll(tasks3.ToArray());
        Task.WaitAll(tasks4.ToArray());
    }));

await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Concat(tasks2));
```

Every method of EveOnlineClient downloads XML to local cache if needed (if local cache has expired), parses it and returns as an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int.Parse(key.Attribute("id").Value)
```

`XAttribute` (and `XElement`) [supports implicit cast to `int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358993) (and other types), this means you can write just:

```
(int)key.Attribute("id")
```

One more advantage of this approach is that it uses the invariant culture, unlike the `Parse()` methods, which use the current culture by default. This is especially important for decimal values, since many cultures use `,` as the decimal separator, not `.`.

And if you're going to use casts for numeric types, you might want to use them for `string` too for consistency, instead of accessing `Value`.

---

```
var tasks
var tasks2
var tasks3
var tasks4
```

Those are not very good variable names, try to make names more descriptive, like `accountStatusTasks`.

Also, it's hard to advise more about the structure of the code when you don't use all those tasks in any way, except to wait for them. I assume that's not all they're good for.

---

There are not many cases where `ContinueWith()` is useful, when you can use `await`. Here, I would make the `Select()` lambda `async`, which also means you can use `await Task.WhenAll()` instead of `Task.WaitAll()`, which blocks a thread unnecessarily:

```
var tasks2 = keys.Select(async key =>
{
    var keyInfo = await EveOnlineClient.GetAPIKeyInfoAsync(key.ID, key.VerificationCode);

    var characters = keyInfo.Characters;

    // Get the sheet for each character in each API key
    var tasks3 = characters.Select(character => EveOnlineClient.GetCharacterSheetAsync(key.ID, key.VerificationCode, character.ID));

    // Get skill in training for each character in each API key
    var tasks4 = characters.Select(character => EveOnlineClient.GetSkillInTrainingAsync(key.ID, key.VerificationCode, character.ID));

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks3.Concat(tasks4));
});
```

---

Quite often, code that makes many requests to a single server in parallel is limited by [`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx), which by default is set to just 2. But if you decide to change this, make sure to follow any [guidelines about rate limiting of the API you're using](https://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/EVE_API#Rate_Limits); otherwise, you might easily end up blocked.

Comment: Using Parse() is not a wrong approach. The connected client might have a culture set which is valid in that context. With your approach, "123,456" could mean 123456 or 123.456. Very different values.

Comment: @VincePanuccio No, with my approach, "123,456" will be always invalid, because the cast uses `.` as decimal separator and no thousand separator. If the format of the XML was culture-dependent, that would be a terrible design, since you couldn't safely transfer it from one computer to another.